# How to set minimize as default in window?

Tags: kendo-ui, window

How to make `action()` in kendo window set minimize as default. My code here :

```
.Actions(actions => actions.Pin().Minimize().Maximize().Close())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function on the window called `minimize()`. I bet that you can simply call that when the window is created.